# Laravel Redirect::route with an array parameter

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Purpose: to redirect a specific route with an array value. I am not able to use View::make in my situation, which causes problem.

```
$value = 'Sarah';

$array_param = array(
   '1' => 'a',
   '2' => 'b'
);

return Redirect::route('myroute', array(
   'name' => $value
));
```

Above is cool. But i cannot use $array_param with redirect route, which expects a string parameter, but i'm sending an array variable. Alternative way?

```
return Redirect::route('myroute', array(
   'name' => $value,
   'parameter' => $array_param
));
```

--update--

```
Route::post('myroute/{name}/{array_param}', array(
        'as' => 'myroute',
        'uses' => 'mycontroller@mymethod'
    ));
```

Comment: What is the route definition for `myroute`?

Comment: **1.** You can't use array route parameters only strings. **2.** You should not redirect to a POST route, period. You should separate your GET/POST logic in such a way that redirects occur only towards GET routes. If you provide more information about the target functionality I can suggest a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the version of Laravel do you have?

The code below works for me correctly on laravel 5.1. Maybe it'll help you.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $item = Item::find(1); // an example
    return redirect()->route('item.show', ['id' => $item->id]);
}
```

and yes, the redirect to the post route looks very incorrect. Please try to use the redirect only to the GET routes.

Comment: will let you know when i give it a try